# Find if a number is between two values and output the larger one in an ascending array

Tags: javascript

I have an ascending array like this,

```
let target = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18];
```

and a variable `userInput` which is a digit within the range of min and max of `target`, how can I find out the value in `target` which is the next larger than `userInput`? I'm trying to write a for-loop but have a feeling this is not efficient at all.

For example, when `userInput = 8`, should output 10; when `userInput = 12`, should output 13.

Comment: Check out binary search on Google

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a for-loop but have a feeling this is not efficient at all."* show us that loop, you might be closer to the solution than you expect

Comment: and yes, binary search is the way to go, in the worst case, you need log2(N) iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try code below [here](https://runkit.com/embed/5ujuk3n0kuyz): https://runkit.com/embed/5ujuk3n0kuyz

Update: below code is even better and right to the point, thanks @dbramwell, @Kamil Augustyniak

```
let target = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18];
let userInput = 8;
const output = target.find( item => item > userInput);
console.log(output);
```

Original:

```
let target = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18];
let userInput = 8;

let output = target.filter( item => item > userInput);
if(output && output.length >0)
    console.log(output[0]);
```

Comment: would `find` be better here? It just returns the first that matches the condition

Comment: `filter` checks whole elements of the array so you do unnecessary checkings

Comment: You don't declare the output variable: `const output = target.find( item => item > userInput);`, use `const` instead of `let`

Answer (score 0):

- *Since your array is sorted*, you can do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) as mentioned in the comments.
- We basically start the search from mid index of the array, if the value at mid index is less than or equal to ``userInput`, we move towards right slice of the array, else we move towards the left slice of the array and do a binary search on that respective slice of the array.
- Binary search is faster than linear search giving you a logarithmic time complexity of **log<sub>2</sub>N** over an **O(N)** search.

```js
let target = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18];
let low = 0,
  high = target.length - 1;
let userInput = 8;
while (low <= high) {
  let mid = low + parseInt((high - low) / 2);
  if (target[mid] <= userInput) low = mid + 1;
  else high = mid - 1;
}

console.log(target[low]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `indexOf` function in JavaScript to achieve this.

```
let target = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18];

let userInput = 13;
let index = target.indexOf(userInput);
if(index != -1 && index < target.length -1) {
    console.log(target[index + 1]);
    // outputs 15
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: No, `userInput` is not necessarily in the `target` array. If not, your code does not work.

Comment: It'll be better if you use `const` instead of `let`. You don't modify these values. `!==` will be better than `!=`